# What is the difference between wrought aluminum and cast aluminum? Is it possible to cast 6061 aluminum?

Tags: materials, metals, aluminum

I'm currently learning about material properties and I'm not certain what the main differences are between the different types of aluminum.

The aluminum I'm most familiar with is 6061-T6 aluminum and just recently learned that there are different "kinds" of aluminum, namely wrought, cast, forged (and maybe extruded? not sure if that's a type). Anyway, I always thought that the 6061 designation referred to the chemical, or alloy composition of the metal, therefore, would it be possible to have 6061 aluminum but melt it down to "cast"? Would it still be 6061?

Comment: Wrought aluminum will typically have anisotropic grains, while cast aluminum will have more uniform grains.  That will affect the mechanical properties.  Forging can also be used for particular alloys that harden, but it is less used because most aluminum alloys don't harden much with deformation.

Melted and recast 6061 would retain its composition and be the same chemical alloy.  But the heat treatment, and the associated grain-size-shape changes, that makes it T6 would have to be redone.

Comment: I see, so essentially the temper would be lost. So it would be 6061 aluminum with an unknown temper then. Is there a designation to state 6061 when it is cast?

Comment: I think it is 6061-O.  Don't have the ASM handbooks, so can't confirm.  But you can look at http://www.matweb.com/search/DataSheet.aspx?MatGUID=626ec8cdca604f1994be4fc2bc6f7f63&ckck=1 and related alloys on Matweb for comparisons.